# Drag and drop right click wpf

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

When I start a drag and drop using a right click in WPF it will fire the drop on any target with out waiting for the right mouse button to come up.

Comment: Can you please tell us what you have tried to do so far?

Comment: I have been using a previewMouse right and left button down event to set get a start point for each click and then on mouse move i check to see if the mouse button is still pressed and if it is over the min drag distance i start a drag drop.  This all works now the problem is on the drop side of things.  I added the following code to the onDrop function i have. if (e.KeyStates != DragDropKeyStates.RightMouseButton) this prevents it form going into the drop mode when I am using the right mouse button for dragging.  However the cursor isn't updating when you go over a target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To drag, the mouse needs to be captured, which can only be achieved when the left mouse button is down.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse(VS.95).aspx (for Silverlight, but I think it's similar).