# WPF DragDrop.DoDragDrop (for a RIGHT-Click?)

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, right-click

In WPF I want to do initiate a drag-drop using the right click. Something like windows explorer, right click, move slightly and you get the adorner to indicate a drag drop in operation.  Don't move and you get the context menu when you let up the button.

I have it all initiated but when I call the "DragDrop.DoDragDrop" it immediately falls right through, it doesn't wait for the mouse up.

I did see this link [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060856/drag-and-drop-right-click-wpf) and it refers to a Silverlight article and the need for the MouseCapture AND it only works with the Left button.  Taken literally, it would seem that it is simply not possible to do a right click drag operation (like windows) in wpf.  I always have a tough time believing such things :) (I did try the MouseCapture to no avail)

Answer (score 0):

Found solution for your problem on [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/16d1d0f7-5fa5-4845-a836-dab01aa575be). The main idea is to use [DragDrop.AddQueryContinueDragHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.dragdrop.addquerycontinuedraghandler%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).