# TextBox - Drag and Drop with Right mouse

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, right-click, wpf-textbox

I'm trying to implement text swapping between 2 TextBoxes. Idea is, you have few of them and as you right-click on one of them, drag and drop on a different one and Text from the 1st one goes to 2nd one, and Text from 2nd one goes to the 1st one. So basically Text swap (Actually later I want to swap font name, size, etc... but one step at the time).

So problem I have is regarding RightClick handlers... By default on right click ContextMenu was showing up so I disabled it (by doing `ContextMenu="{x:Null}"`).
I already know that adding handlers to `MouseRightButtonDown` not gonna work so I'm adding it to `PreviewMouseRightButtonDown` and C# code for it looks like that:

```
private void PreviewMouseRightButtonDownHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop( e.Source as DependencyObject,
                         (sender as Textbox).Text,
                         DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

Now when I press right mouse button over my TextBox this function is executed. Unfortunatelly as soon as I move my mouse a bit Text is getting pasted to the same TextBox :/ And I don't understand why...
If I use PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown it's not behaving in same way and I'm able to drag mouse cursor out of TextBox.



I found similar question in here => [WPF DragDrop.DoDragDrop (for a RIGHT-Click?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476547/wpf-dragdrop-dodragdrop-for-a-right-click)
and was trying to add `DragDrop.AddQueryContinueDragHandler(this, QueryContinueDragHandler);` bit in my code but that doesn't seem to work :/
Also it's been like 5 years since then so maybe something has changed since then.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how you add the `QueryContinueDragHandler` (maybe by code?) but in this way "right button d&d" works for me (of course I got inspired by the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476547/wpf-dragdrop-dodragdrop-for-a-right-click) you linked)

In the XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBox Margin="10"
                PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="PreviewMouseRightButtonDownHandler"
                DragDrop.PreviewQueryContinueDrag="QueryContinueDragHandler" />
    <TextBox Margin="10" Text="Drag me"
                PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="PreviewMouseRightButtonDownHandler"
                DragDrop.PreviewQueryContinueDrag="QueryContinueDragHandler" />
</StackPanel>
```

And in the code behind:

```
private void PreviewMouseRightButtonDownHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(e.Source as DependencyObject,
            textBox.Text, DragDropEffects.Move);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
private void QueryContinueDragHandler(object source, QueryContinueDragEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = source as TextBox;

    e.Handled = true;

    if (e.EscapePressed)
    {
        e.Action = DragAction.Cancel;
        return;
    }            

    if ((e.KeyStates & DragDropKeyStates.LeftMouseButton) != DragDropKeyStates.None)
    {
        e.Action = DragAction.Continue;
        return;
    }

    if ((e.KeyStates & DragDropKeyStates.RightMouseButton) != DragDropKeyStates.None)
    {
        e.Action = DragAction.Continue;
        return;
    }

    e.Action = DragAction.Drop;

    if (textBox != null)
    {
        textBox.Text = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Hey, I was adding `QueryContinueDragHandler` by code. So obviously I've messed up somehow. I tried your way (added in XAML) and it's working like a charm. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Actually, bonus question :V How do I access `destination` in `QueryContinueDragHandler`? Because now I moving text from one field to another works, but I can't swap it. I guess perfect fit for it would be just before `textBox.Text = String.Empty;` but I don't know how to get object we've dropped on. Was also trying to add Drop handler but it's not getting executed if TextBox is not empty...

Comment: Did you try to add in your XAML a `PreviewDragOver` handler to the destination control? Something like `PreviewDragOver="PreviewDragOver"`

Comment: I did but `PreviewDragOver` is being called hundred of times. I ended up hacking it around by replacing 2nd parameter of DoDragDrop function (`textBox.Text`) with DataObject where I'm adding DragSource data. Then in `PreviewDrop` function I do `e.Data.GetData("DragSource");`. Works, but it feels like massive workaround...