# Is it possible to handle Thumb.DragDelta with right mouse click?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, slider

```
Thumb.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(Thumb_DragDelta);
```

Is it possible to handle this method with RightMouseButtonDown instead of LeftButtonDown?

Thanks

Comment: chek http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060856/drag-and-drop-right-click-wpf... it appears it is not possible, unless you code it all yourself :(

Comment: okay...I am implementing a drag behavior manually.